Cant Run google-chrome due to erroe
the error:
[14860:14860:0801/121157.310820:ERROR:message_box_dialog.cc(144)] Unable to show a dialog outside the UI thread message loop: Google Chrome - The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process (5135) on another computer (p-ubuntu).  Chrome has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted.  If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chrome.
but i am on (p-ubuntu)<-device name  . i am new to linux and cant figure it out how to properly search error codes .
For context: I duel boot windows 11 and ubuntu 22.04 desktop and have already restarted my laptop and reinstalled google-chrome already . i ran "google-chrome" command,in terminal window.

I got a similar message yesterday on 24.04, but while attempting to start Chromium / snap (Chromium wouldn't start). Removing / reinstalling the snap did the trick (I had to manually restore my user data by uncompressing /var/lib/snapd/snapshots/1_chromium_*.zip (after the removal) and by copying over my profiles (just "Default") back to the snap's directory: cp -r Default ~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/).

I ran the command in terminal window for google-chrome:
 rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock
and for cromium-Borwser:
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium/Singleton
but a warning it will delete all cookies and data . you will need to relogin.
source : https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4860

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
